# Do I need to change any values?

Tags: rf, circuit-design, noise

I am trying to simplify my noise source circuit from the first design to the second. Can anyone help me correct the values I need to do this as lost and a novice?

Also, will this produce noise as I am attempting to do?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Version 2][image: Version 1]

Comment: What kind of noise?  Pink, white, popcorn etc.?

Comment: If I succeeded the "Find the differences between two pictures" only C4 and C6 have been added. If they are located close to C1 and C5 on the PCB, they hardly help with filtering/stabilizing. (If they do, you should rather improve the source (12V source+cabling) than use these caps!). **So**, do show/tell where these C4 and C6 are located on the PCB...

Comment: the U2 has no current path for the Vin+.

Comment: Sorry I was just wondering because now I am sharing current in the one with fewer components do I need to modify any of the other components to compensate? Also, this is a white noise generator 1-300MHz with the possibility of increasing the complexity by duplication.